# How to return a VkPhysicalDevice from vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm following a game engine tutorial in Vulkan and came across an issue where vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices is populating my 'devices' vector with pointers to the stack. VkPhysicalDevice appears to be the typedef of a pointer, VkPhysicalDevice_T*. I get a warning on Visual Studio about this issue, and I'm wondering if there's a way to have the function allocate to heap instead.

Edit: At "return devices[i]" I get the warning "C26816: The pointer points to memory allocated on the stack."

```
VkPhysicalDevice VulkanRenderer::selectPhysicalDevice() {
    U32 deviceCount = 0;
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(_instance, &deviceCount, nullptr);
    if (deviceCount == 0) {
        Logger::Fatal("No supported physical device was found.");
    }
    std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice> devices(deviceCount);
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(_instance, &deviceCount, devices.data());

    for (U32 i = 0; i < deviceCount; ++i) {
        if (physicalDeviceMeetsRequirements(devices[i])) {
            return devices[i];
        }
    }

    Logger::Fatal("No devices found which meet application requirements.");
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: What "warning" are you getting? The code doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas it's warning that I'm returning a pointer with allocated memory on the stack

Comment: So... why is it warning about that? Please edit your post to provide the *exact* warning message. And your compiler build options.

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear. I am returning devices[i] which is populated by vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices. I am wondering why this function is populating on the stack and if it's possible to populate on the heap. If this function is meant to populate on the stack, then I'm confused as to why this is

Comment: You still haven't provided the *exact warning message*. There's nothing "populated on the stack" (whatever that even means) by your code. Can you please just edit your question and copy/paste in the exact error message you're getting, as well as some indication of what the line number is? And again, provide compiler build options.

Comment: edited the post to include warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this one too. It comes from static analysis related to the newish C++ guidelines.

The dispatchable handles in Vulkan are pointer-like things. The modern C++ conventions do not like raw pointers though. The static analyzer seems to incorrectly think the `std:vector` is tied to the lifetime of whatever is under that pointer.

At the time of writing, this code seems to avoid the static analyzer warning:

```
const VkPhysicalDevice d = devices[0];
return d;
```

Additionally, the warning could just be specifically silenced:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning( suppress: 26816 )
#endif
return devices[0];
```